# Button size is automatically changing

Tags: ios

I'm adding buttons (image button) on viewcontroller for modal connections to other viewcontroller. when i sometimes look buttons in iphone simulator, buttons size is changing(by itself). and i created new buttons but this problem can be again.
what is the problem? what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: When do the button change size?

Comment: thanks. problem was "use autolaout" enable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable auto layout in Interface Builder

Comment: Please add more detail to improve the quality of your answer.